# MvxIoCResolveException during RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross

During invocation RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart, I get exception:
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to find constructor for type MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigationServiceAppStart
Everything works well during debugging. But when I build in release and prepare an apk, I get this exception.
Below I paste the log from device monitor:

> 03-01 14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855): Unhandled Exception: 03-01
>   14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):
>   MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to find
>   constructor for type
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigationServiceAppStart`1
>     [[AppMMobile.DataService.ViewModels.MainViewModel,
>   AppMMobile.DataService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] 03-01 14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type
>   type) [0x0002b] in :0  03-01
>   14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.IocConstruct[T] () [0x00006] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton[TInterface,TType]
>   () [0x00006] in :0  03-01
>   14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication.RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart[TViewModel]
>   () [0x00000] in <593dd944ead4429db9881ce186989310>:0  03-01
>   14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):   at
>   MappMMobile.DataService.App.Initialize () [0x0001a] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeApp
>   (MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.IMvxPluginManager pluginManager,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxApplication app) [0x00007] in
>   <593dd944ead4429db9881ce186989310>:0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x000b4] in
>   <593dd944ead4429db9881ce186989310>:0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.b__7_0
>   (System.Object ignored) [0x00000] in
>   <9d2864708eca4fb99992263d063bbc38>:0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context
>   (System.Object state) [0x00007] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem
>   () [0x00021] in :0  03-01
>   14:10:49.667: E/mono(21855):   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in
>   :0  03-01 14:10:49.667:
>   E/mono(21855):   at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback ()
>   [0x00000] in :0

```
    public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
            public override void Initialize()
            {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart<ViewModels.MainViewModel>();
            [Registering my types...]
            }
     }
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, it is difficult to reproduce your problem from you question.

Comment: What are your settings for the Linker in the AndroidOptions?

Comment: I have selected Sdk and User Assemblies

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a file `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` inside your android project with [this content](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/nuspec/DroidContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Core.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    // This class is never actually executed, but when Xamarin linking is enabled it does how to ensure types and properties
    // are preserved in the deployed app
    public class LinkerPleaseInclude
    {
        public void Include(Button button)
        {
            button.Click += (s,e) => button.Text = button.Text + "";
        }

        public void Include(CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            checkBox.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(Switch @switch)
        {
            @switch.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => @switch.Checked = !@switch.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(View view)
        {
            view.Click += (s, e) => view.ContentDescription = view.ContentDescription + "";
        }

        public void Include(TextView text)
        {
            text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
        }

        public void Include(CheckedTextView text)
        {
            text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
        }

        public void Include(CompoundButton cb)
        {
            cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(SeekBar sb)
        {
            sb.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => sb.Progress = sb.Progress + 1;
        }

        public void Include(RadioGroup radioGroup)
        {
            radioGroup.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => radioGroup.Check(args.CheckedId);
        }

        public void Include(RadioButton radioButton)
        {
            radioButton.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => radioButton.Checked = args.IsChecked;
        }

        public void Include(RatingBar ratingBar)
        {
            ratingBar.RatingBarChange += (sender, args) => ratingBar.Rating = 0 + ratingBar.Rating;
        }

        public void Include(Activity act)
        {
            act.Title = act.Title + "";
        }

        public void Include(INotifyCollectionChanged changed)
        {
            changed.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => { var test = $"{e.Action}{e.NewItems}{e.NewStartingIndex}{e.OldItems}{e.OldStartingIndex}"; };
        }
        public void Include(ICommand command)
        {
            command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) => { if (command.CanExecute(null)) command.Execute(null); };
        }

        public void Include(MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector injector)
        {
            injector = new MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector ();
        } 
        public void Include(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged changed)
        {
            changed.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>  {
                var test = e.PropertyName;
            };
        }

        public void Include(MvxTaskBasedBindingContext context)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            var context2 = new MvxTaskBasedBindingContext();
            context2.Dispose();
        }
        public void Include(MvxNavigationService service, IMvxViewModelLoader loader)
        {
            service = new MvxNavigationService(null, loader);
        }
        public void Include(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            Console.Write("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            color = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        }
    }
}
```

It will ensure that the linker does not strip classes, properties, etc needed for MvvmCross to work. That is what is probably happening

HIH